# IndexedDB DB Datas To XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, indexeddb

In my project, I have to create a XML file from my IndexedDB datas. I am passing that XML file to my WebService that will save my datas to my Server.. And in return, I also want to read and parse XML file (or data) sent by my WebService.. So give me some suggestions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you write a REST service. This will interface a lot easier with the indexeddb. On the service you can parse the json data into objects you can save into the database.

Comment: can you post some piece of code.. Also tell me that it is safe to use REST service because I want the datas to be very safe..

Comment: Well, a rest service takes advantage ot the http protocol. It uses the verbs like het, post, put, delete,... To determine the action that needs To Be preformed. The data It self is sent in a json format. I don't know which Technology You are Using, but I'm a .net Guy. In .net You can use asp.net mvc webapi To do it. Of You want It To Be secure, the best way To do that is Using https for the services and even Your web app.

Comment: I am also a .net programmer but I am not using MVC.. i'm using normal asp.net application but it has to be have offline capablity.. Are you saying about XMLHttpRequest?? Is it really secured?? Bcoz the datas can be seen in the response headers itself.. Thats why I m wondering to use it or not??

Comment: If you send XML, it will be the same, the only way to secure data is by using SSL. This will encrypt your data on the wire. Advantage of the ASP.NET MVC Web API is that you can use the ASP.NET stack for security (authorization and authentication)

Comment: You can find here (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) a tutorial of the use of Web API

Comment: But i am not using MVC architecture, can I still use it or what about ASP.NET webservice (.asmx pages) and XMLHttpRequest??...

Comment: You can mix classic ASP.NET WebForms with ASP.NET MVC Web API. You should be able to install the WebAPI on your current project by using nuget.

Comment: Can't I use **.asmx WebService** which is already available with asp.net?? Or is there any problem in using that??

Comment: You van do that, but in that case you need to use SOAP messages. That means you need to write javascript code to parse the XML data into a JSON format

Comment: okay, can I convert my IDB datas to xml or json format and send it to server via my .asmx web service and getting error info as json or xml format from web service and save it in my IDB??

Comment: Below code is correct or do I need to change something:

`var sXml = "<Applicant_Details>";
cursor.onsuccess = function() {
   sXml += "/n<Applicant>";
   sXml += "/n/t<Id>"+result.value["id"]+"</Id>";
   sXml += "/n/t<AM_Applicant_Name>"+result.value["AM_Applicant_Name"]+"</AM_Applicant_Name>";
   sXml += "/n</Applicant>";
result.continue();
}

trans.oncomplete = function() {
    sXml += "/n</Applicant_Details>";
    alert(sXml);
    console.log(sXml);
}`

Answer (score 1):

IDB "object stores" can only store JavaScript objects. To save XML data to an IDB database you'll need to transform the XML object into a JavaScript object. That function will depend on your XML needs - there's no one-size-fits-all approach to XML transformation.

In general, [follow the advice I laid out for you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22385349/317937) in translating your XML objects into a JSON representation:

> For example, if your SQL table looked like this:
>
> ```
> +------+--------+--------+
> |      | ColA   | ColB   |
> +------+--------+--------+
> | Row1 | CellA1 | CellB1 |
> | Row2 | CellA2 | CellB2 |
> | Row3 | CellA3 | CellB3 |
> +------+--------+--------+
> ```
>
> Your JavaScript object may look like this:
>
> ```
> var myObjectToStore = {
>     'Row1': { 'ColA': 'CellA1', 'ColB': 'CellB1' },
>     'Row2': { 'ColA': 'CellA2', 'ColB': 'CellB2' },
>     'Row3': { 'ColA': 'CellA3', 'ColB': 'CellB3' }
> };
> ```
>
> The JSON representation of that object is very similar:
>
> ```
> {
>   "Row1": {
>     "ColA": "CellA1",
>     "ColB": "CellB1"
>   },
>   "Row2": {
>     "ColA": "CellA2",
>     "ColB": "CellB2"
>   },
>   "Row3": {
>     "ColA": "CellA3",
>     "ColB": "CellB3"
>   }
> }
> ```

It's far easier to use JavaScript objects without such serialization. I would highly suggest exploring using JSON over the network rather than XML.

Modern browsers all support `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify` and most web servers can handle the `application/json` mimetype.